# How do I implement a Ruby only command line application?

Tags: ruby, console-application

How to implement a ruby application which is completely operated via console (terminal) ? This application may be a calculator . This should also store the results and display it whenever needed.

Comment: As it stands this question is far too broad. You read input, you write output. There are many ways you could persist data, but if it's relational, use a relational DB. If it's not, it may not matter what you use.

Comment: would you please provide any source for me to refer

Comment: Any code that writes to a database using any of the database gems that are available? Or just write to files, or JSON, or... There's just no way to answer this question in a general way: there are countless options. I'd consider searching the web for available options, picking one, and trying it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a Ruby command-line script:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

This is because Ruby is command-line by default, and only "web" when running as part of a web framework.

Now what you probably mean is "how can I make a useful command-line tool"? I'd suggest by sticking to command-line conventions and making use of built-in utilities like [OptionParser](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/OptionParser.html) so you can have robust command-line arguments. As per the documentation:

```
require 'optparse'

options = { }

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
    options[:verbose] = v
  end
end.parse!
```

Then you can run your script like:

```
example -v
```

Which turns on the "verbose" flag. Look at how other commands work for examples and conventions, including those offered by `ruby` itself:

```
ruby -h
```

Comment: But I need know how to access and store data.

Comment: That's entirely up to you. What data? What access? Every situation is different.